# How to print contents from a session variable by looping in a foreach statement

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to write a code where can print and loop through the contents of my session variable by using a foreach statement

here is my code

```
<form class="form form-inline" method = "post" action="reportmaker.php">
<select name="rfield">
<option value="">--Select Field--</option>
<?php
    $sc2=mysql_query("SELECT * from searchcolumn s left join report_fields r on s.scol_id=r.field_id where s.category != 'wh'");
    foreach($sc2 as $sc){
 ?>

<option value="<?php echo $sc[advsearch_col]; ?>"><?php echo $sc[advsearch_name]; ?></option>

 <?php
  }
 ?>
 </select>
 <button type="submit" value = "submit" id="add" name="add" class="btn pull-right">Add More</button>

</form>

<?php
        if(isset($_POST['add']))
            {
            $_SESSION['temp'][]=$_POST['rfield'];   

            }
        if($_SESSION[temp][]!=""){
            foreach($_SESSION[temp][] as $temp)
            {
        echo $temp;
            }
        }
        ?>
```

the error that appears with this code is

Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading

the line where the error is is this

```
if($_SESSION[temp][]!=""){
```

i need to print the contents of the session array and this is the only way i know how
is there a way to fix this?

thanks

=========EDIT

thanks for the answers guys i finally got it

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['add']))
        {
        $_SESSION['temp'][]=$_POST['rfield'];   

        }
    if($_SESSION['temp']!=""){
        foreach($_SESSION['temp'] as $temp)
        {
    echo $temp;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

The empty brackets are merely syntactic sugar for easy **appending** at the end of the array.

Also, even though it did not cause a problem here, be careful to properly quote `'temp'` and do not use `temp`. If there is no `temp` constant defined, it will take the corresponding string value `'temp'`, but if such a constant is defined elsewhere such as this `define('temp', 'value')`, using `temp` will use the defined value instead.

Comment: tried this code and this error appears
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: well you need to ensure that $_SESSION['temp'] is an array, like by using a different test such as: `if (is_array($_SESSION['temp'])) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

This will give you each post field that you added to the session `temp` array. You don't need the `if` before the `foreach`. You might want to check if it's set though before looping:

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['temp']))
    {
       foreach($_SESSION['temp'] as $temp)
```

Throughout your code you access array elements with `$array[keyname]` which is not good, you should use quotes around the key name. The reason for this is, without quotes, PHP treats it as a constant, and if not found falls back to a string. So if you had a constant with the same name, you'd have problems.

Answer (score 0):

empty brackets [] are used to add something to the array. To use the whole array, leave out the empty brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_SESSION["temp"] as $temp)
{
echo $temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm only assuming you are debugging. To print arrays you can use the function `print_r($array);`.

For debugging I usually use `var_dump($var);` because it also shows some additional details like datatype and such.

If you want to use a foreach loop for any reason, it's very easy:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $value) echo $value;
```